# Squid as cache proxy

Tags: proxy, cache, squid, transparent-proxy

The only internet connection I have is through mobile data, although I have an unlimited use in the browsers for the cache, to optimize the bandwidth and not have to be downloading the css and js files again maybe because of the time of expiration that the sites have defined. I would like to install a squid to navigate through the squid and maybe so I can increase the cache and optimize my data connection. I have searched the net and I have seen very good reviews about this, but I am not sure that it is a good idea and that it is really worth it, please, I need an opinion, if someone has already done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a *real* answer, it's a frame challenge.

If you don't have multiple clients, squid will offer few, if any, benefits over browser caching.

Browsers cache content, but the cache is local to the browser. Squid shares it cache among clients. As long as you have few clients, this doesn't really make sense.

In addition, most traffic those days are TLS. Caching this with squid requires configuring certificates to allow squid to read traffic. The browser, on the other hand, is able to cache TLS content without any configuration.

What you *should* do is use some kind of ad and script blocker in your browser. Those can reduce the amount to download significantly.

Comment: Hello @vidarlo, thank very much for your answer, I have to try it.